# String.Join with String concatenation: Code Improvement

Tags: c#, .net, string, concatenation

I currently have a `List(Of String)` named `docIds` that looks a bit as follows:

```
{A3001,A40001,BF0003,13458}
```

it only contains letters and numbers. I would like to output that array as follows (for use in a DQL Query)

```
'A3001','A40001','BF0003','13458'
```

Off course i used the `String.Join` method

```
String.Join(",",docIds.ToArray())
Output: A3001,A40001,BF0003,13458
```

I know of 2 (non-performant) methods to add those quotes

- Method 1:
      Before the `String.Join`, `iterate` every string in list and add the quotes.
- Method 2:
      The following String operation:

  ```
      "'" + String.Join(",",docIds.ToArray()).Replace(",","','") + "'"
  ```

**Question:** Is there a more performant/Proper way to achieve the desired result?

Comment: If you are using String Concatenation for joining large numbers of strings, its better to use `StringBuilder` for a better performance.

Comment: Even when the Strings are already stored inside a List?

Comment: You don't need the `ToArray()` on `docIds` in your above examples. `String.Join` has [overloads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join.aspx) to work with an IEnumberable. With the `ToArray`, you add extra work that has to be done before the function can be called.

Comment: If you are storing the joined string into another string variable.

Comment: @crashmstr: thanks for the Tip! I didn't know that! ChandanRoy: Thanks for pointing this out to me. I wasn't aware that, looks like i have some modifications to do :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use LINQ:

```
string.Join(",", docIds.Select(id => string.Format("'{0}'", id)));
```

This overload of [`String.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) was added in .NET 4.0, before you need to add `ToArray` to create a `string[]`.

Comment: Beautifull, Absolute Beautifull! Works like a charm and looks way better in my code aswell! I'll accept the answer as soon as SO allows me to!